# Link de um menu para um marcador no Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou usando o API do Google Maps para mostrar a localização de algumas lojas da empresa. Eu utilizei [esse tutorial](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/google-apis/google-maps-api-v3-criando-um-mapa-personalizado.html) para conseguir.

Até aqui tudo bem. Mas o problema é que tenho um menu com as localizações do mapa e gostaria de linká-los para cada marcador dentro do mapa. Como faço isso?

Aqui vai o que tenho até agora:

```js
var map;
var idInfoBoxOpened;
var infoBox = [];
var markers = [];

function initialize() { 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.922787, -43.945141);

    var options = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("innerMapa"), options);
}

initialize();

function abrirInfoBox(id, marker) {
    if (typeof(idInfoBoxOpened) == 'number' && typeof(infoBox[idInfoBoxOpened]) == 'object') {
        infoBox[idInfoBoxOpened].close();
    }

    infoBox[id].open(map, marker);
    idInfoBoxOpened = id;
}

function loadSpots() {

    $.getJSON('path/to/marker/spots.json', function(spots) {

        $.each(spots, function(index, spot) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(spot.Latitude, spot.Longitude),
                title: "Find a nearby store",
                map: map,
                icon: '/path/to/image/spot.png'
            });


            var myOptions = {
                content: spot.Texto,
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-150, 0)
            };

            infoBox[spot.Id] = new InfoBox(myOptions);
            infoBox[spot.Id].marker = marker;

            infoBox[spot.Id].listener = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
                abrirInfoBox(spot.Id, marker);
            });
        });
    });

};

loadSpots();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu menu você precisa ter um atributo de dado. Onlcick você pega esse dado, faz o loop na sua lista de markers e dispara o evento de click.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
```

Comment: Nossa, exatamente! Eu também precisei também alimentar o marker com as propriedades do local usando: `markers[ponto.Id]=marker;`